# How to Drag & Drop file upload with MDBootstrap and jQuery

Tags: jquery, mdbootstrap

I'm using MDBootstrap with jQuery and the plugin for drag & drop file uploads.  I have the Pro plugin and use the HTML:

```
<div class="file-upload-wrapper">
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <input type="file" id="input-file-now" class="file_upload" />
    </div>
</div>

<!-- SCRIPTS -->
<!-- JQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap tooltips -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/popper.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- MDB core JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/mdb.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/addons/datatables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/addons/mdb-file-upload.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $('.file_upload').file_upload();
</script>
```

I've added a button before and used that to submit the form and it works, I can process the form, but there has to be some functionality built into the plug in for AJAX upload, but the documentation on HOW is lacking.  Can anyone help me out?

I've tried adding `console.log('success');` to the `file_upload()` inside an anonymous function like

```
$('file_upload').file_upload(functin(){
     console.log('successful upload');
});
```

but this did nothing.

Comment: Typo, file_upload(functin() must be file_upload(function().

Comment: That was not the issue.  I think that I'm missing some libraries or something.  I'll post the entire code in a minute.